# angular js templateUrl fails to load with mvc multi language route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes, single-page-application

i am working on SPA with mvc , and  recently created SPA framework and configured with visual studio 2015 default Mvc templet , and all works good . but when configured my mvc application with internationalization with following blog 
[tutorial](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx), my angular js fails to load ..

this is my mvc route

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



    }
}
```

this is my angular module

```
"use strict";
 angular.module("eaFramework").directive("eaFramework", function () {
return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        title: '@',
        subtitle: '@',
        iconFile: '@'
    },
    controller: "eaFrameworkController",
   // templateUrl:"/ext-modules/eaFramework/eaFrameworkTemplate.html"
    templateUrl: '/Home/SPAHeaderTemplet'
};});
```

the templet  `templateUrl: '/Home/SPAHeaderTemplet'` url in this module fails to load .

here is screen shot of browser [image: screenshot]

where i am mistaken , idont know , help required .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when $compile attempts to fetch a template from some URL, and the request fails.

To resolve this error, ensure that the URL of the template is spelled correctly and resolves to correct absolute URL.

If you are using $templateCache to pre-load templates, ensure that the cache was populated with the template.

Comment: every this was working perfect before applying internationalization in default MVC templet

Comment: Try hitting the same template url from POSTMAN or RestClient, see if the path to template is correct or got modified